# Display images on google map markers using viewinfowindow

Tags: javascript, image, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I am trying to display images when user clicks on marker but unable to make it. The map id displayed and the marker too,but when I click on marker it isn't showing any image. Can anyone help me in displaying images:
Here is my code :

```
<html>
        <body>
    <head>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
       </script>
<script>
       var x=12.35;
       var y=14.25;
       var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(x,y);

       function initialize()
       {
       var mapProp = {
                      center:myCenter,
                      zoom:10,
                      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                      };

       var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

       var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                      position:myCenter,
                                          });

       marker.setMap(map);

       var infowindow=new google.maps.Infowindow({
                                                  content:'<div><img src="download.png"></img></div>'
                                                });
       infowindow.open(map,marker);
       }
       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
       <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is viewinfowindow?

Answer (score 1):

First issue is with `google.maps.Infowindow` it should be `google.maps.InfoWindow`. Capitalization matters!

That will resolve the issue with the window not opening.

For getting your popup to open and close on mouse click you will need to add click handlers to your `marker` like so.

```
        var currentPopup; 

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            if (currentPopup != null) {
                currentPopup.close();
                currentPopup = null;
            }
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            currentPopup = infowindow;
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, "closeclick", function() {
            map.panTo(center);
            currentPopup = null;
        });
```

The first method adds an event listener to the `marker` and assigns it to a variable to ensure that multiple `InfoWindows` are not generated then opens the popup. The `closeclick` method nulls out the variable which closes the popup.

```js
        var x=12.35;
        var y=14.25;
        var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(x,y);

        function initialize()
        {
            var mapProp = {
                center:myCenter,
                zoom:10,
                mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

            var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                position:myCenter,
            });

            marker.setMap(map);

            var infowindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content:'<div><img src="icon.png"></img></div>'
            });

            var currentPopup;

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                if (currentPopup != null) {
                    currentPopup.close();
                    currentPopup = null;
                }
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                currentPopup = infowindow;
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, "closeclick", function() {
                map.panTo(center);
                currentPopup = null;
            });

        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<head>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```